# Not passing image url or text for facebook sharing in android

Tags: android, facebook-share

I want to share a **picture url and a description** in facebook by clicking a button in android.

Now when I click popes up the complete action using dialog with facebook. When I open facebook by that description or picture url is **not passed**.

(I don't want to use facebook sdk share button because I want to add twitter for this too.)

My code;

```
shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {;
                String message = "Share text";
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                Uri screenuri = Uri.parse(pinfo.getSubImage());//getting image url
                try{
                    InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(screenuri);
                }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenuri);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, message);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with friends"));

            }
        });
```

Please help me on this.